# How to fix SafeAreaLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, safearealayoutguide

I am making a game with canvas. The game is clipped because of the top notch, I've tried `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` but nothing happened. Please look at the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
-(void) createGLView {
    //create our openglview and size it correctly
    OpenGLView *glView = [[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:self.appDelegate.initFrame];

    self.view = glView;
    self.appDelegate.canvas = glView;

    core_init_gl(1);

    glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    glView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [glView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:glView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:glView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:glView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:glView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

    int w = self.appDelegate.screenWidthPixels;
    int h = self.appDelegate.screenHeightPixels;
    tealeaf_canvas_resize(w, h);

    NSLOG(@"{tealeaf} Created GLView (%d, %d)", w, h);
}
```

The red color goes inside the top notch. I mean full screen. How to solve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to pinch your glView to its superviews's safeArea. Like this [glView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a fullscreen parent view. Then you can add the `OpenGLView` as subview and connect its constraints to the parent view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

```
- (void)createGLView {

    OpenGLView *glView = [[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:self.appDelegate.initFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:glView];

    self.appDelegate.canvas = glView;

    core_init_gl(1);

    glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    glView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [glView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [glView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

    int w = self.appDelegate.screenWidthPixels;
    int h = self.appDelegate.screenHeightPixels;
    tealeaf_canvas_resize(w, h);

    NSLOG(@"{tealeaf} Created GLView (%d, %d)", w, h);
}
```